# Как задействовать Yandex Translate API v1.5?

Tags: php

Получил бесплатный API-ключ.
Ввожу в строку запроса:

```
translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr/translate?key=<тут мой ключ>&text=close&lang=en-ru
```

И получаю в браузере:

```
Yandex.Translate API documentation can be found here: http://api.yandex.ru/translate/
```

И это вместо перевода. В формате xml тот же ответ.

Пишу код:

```
$params = array( 'key' => '<тут мой ключ>', 'text' => 'close', 'lang' => 'en-ru',); 
$query = http_build_query($params); 
$response = file_get_contents('translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?'.$query);
```

В отладчике вижу что `$response = FALSE`.

Есть пример рабочего куска кода для работы с Yandex Translate API v1.5?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Плохо документацию читаете, или весь код покажите. Делаю так:

```
https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=Мой ключ&text=close&lang=en-ru&format=plain&options=0
```

Ответ:

```
{"code":200,"lang":"en-ru","text":["закрыть"]}
```

Или так, с определением языка на автомате:

```
https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=Мой ключ&text=close&lang=ru&format=plain&options=1
```

Ответ:

```
{"code":200,"detected":{"lang":"en"},"lang":"en-ru","text":["закрыть"]}
```

Ну и примеров кода в сети хватает, например можно так:

```
$url = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?' .
        'key=Мой ключ' .
        'text=close&' .
        'lang=ru&' .
        'format=plain&' .
        'options=1';

$curlObject = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$responseData = curl_exec($curlObject);

curl_close($curlObject);

if ($responseData === false) {
    throw new Exception('Response false');
}

var_dump(json_decode($responseData, true));
```

Comment: А как получить не один вариант перевода ("закрыть") в данном контексте, а :
close [kləʊs] прил
близкий
(near)
close friend – близкий друг
тесный, закрытый, замкнутый, узкий
(tight, indoor, closed, narrow)
close cooperation – тесное сотрудничество
close mouth – закрытый рот
closed curve – замкнутая кривая
тщательный, внимательный
(careful)
close supervision – тщательное наблюдение
close examination – внимательное изучение
плотный
(dense)
close contact – плотный контакт
close гл
закрывать
(shut)
close the valve – закрывать клапан
замыкать
(lock)
заканчивать
(end)

Comment: 2 месяца назад Гугль давал такой перевод, а сейчас нет